# Weird behavior when passing * as a command line parameter on linux

Tags: c, linux, shell, command-line-arguments, glob

I have this very simple c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char ** argv){
  printf ("%s\n",argv[1]);
}
```

When running it on Linux/bash like so:

```
./a.out *
```

I get the following output:

```
a.c
```

why?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shell usage.

Comment: @H2CO3: Sort of. If Yigal is used to Windows/DOS, there the shell does not interpret anything and * is passed to the program which needs to link in a library or handle * itself.

Comment: Don't downvote this question. I haven't ROFL'd this hard in quite a while -- it has some serious entertainment value. :D

Comment: I agree with @ThorX89, instead of just clicking downvote, place some reason why downvote?

Comment: @AmitPandya ThorX89 was joking. And the reason is right there in my first comment.

Comment: What happens when you type `echo *`. Next question, modify your program `a.c` so that it prints out all arguments. Then you can see how the shell works with the glob character exactly.

Comment: I am not sure why is it labeled as off-topic. This question is in the programming domain under a very specific context - exactly the content for stack overflow. I think. 

This page, had it existed when I started debugging, would have save me at least one hour of pondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know that, but when running a command line that has a glob character , such as * or ?, the command line interpreter first expands the character and only then run the program.

For example, if your program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char ** argv){
  int i;
  printf ("argc=%d\n",argc);
  for (i=0;i<argc;i++){
    printf("%d: %s\n",i,argv[i]);
  }
}
```

and you run it like so:

```
./a.out *
```

, then the output will be:

```
argc=4
0: ./a.out
1: a.c
2: a.c~
3: a.out
```

Of course, the output will depend on the content of the current directory.

Answer (score 6):

Because `*` is a glob character that expands to the list of files in the current directory.

If you want to pass a literal `*` you will need to quote or escape it:

```
./a.out '*'
```

Comment: In this case, the OP likely had his source file in the same directory as the compiled executable. I wish more amateur programmer's knew of this feature... sure beats handling wildcards yourself.